# Intellij Run/Debug Configurations, how to set Main Class from another module

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

My project structure is like this:

```
project
   --common
   --moduleA
```

I am trying to run moduleA, however, I would like to use the Main class defined in common. In Intellij's 
Run/Debug Configurations. There are two settings 1) Main class 2) Use classpath of module.

If I use Main class from common, then I have to set 2) to project.common, otherwise it cannot find that main.
If I set 2) to project.common, all classes under moduleA are not visible.

Have someone had the same issue ?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: facing the same problem. did you found any solution?

Comment: @SomnathSingh please see if the answer below helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [module dependencies are configured correctly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency).

If `moduleA` depends on `common` and you select the classpath of `moduleA` in the run configuration, you'll be able to select classes from both `common` and `moduleA` modules.